# CAKEPHP Do I have to set $this->data in the controller for it to work with the form helper

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I would like to set $this->data in a view rather than the controller. Will this work with the form helper to automagically input values?

many thanks!

Further explanation if you really want to know...
You may wonder why I wouldn't just put the values right into the value field but it makes sense in this situation to put it into $this->data; I have a ton of fields of various types and I do not want to have to add if isset() to every value field because form fields are generated based on a stored value and may or may not have already been filled in. I cannot set this->data in the controller because of the data being in JSON. Plus the data has to go through several layers before getting to where it is at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unresolved but I got around it by entering everything manually. It would have been nice to add it automagically.